# What is an M-I word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an ***M-I Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| M-I Words™ | Not M-I Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| DIE | DICE |
| FOX | HOUND |
| LOVE | HATE |
| OASIS | DESERT |
| ROUND | SPHERE |
| MONEY | CASH |
| PARADE | CIRCUS |
| SPHINX | EGYPT |
| BULLET | TRIGGER |
| DESPAIR | HOPE |
| FERRET | RAT |
| WIZARD | PICKPOCKET |
| DESSERT | DINNER |
| MEANING | SAYING |
| EXTERNAL | INTERNAL |
| KEYBOARD | CONTROLLER |
| GENERATION | ANCESTRY |
| SCREWDRIVER | HAMMER |

And, if you want to analyse, here is a CSV version:

```
M-I Words™,Not M-I Words™
DIE,DICE
FOX,HOUND
LOVE,HATE
OASIS,DESERT
ROUND,SPHERE
MONEY,CASH
PARADE,CIRCUS
SPHINX,EGYPT
BULLET,TRIGGER
DESPAIR,HOPE
FERRET,RAT
WIZARD,PICKPOCKET
DESSERT,DINNER
MEANING,SAYING
EXTERNAL,INTERNAL
KEYBOARD,CONTROLLER
GENERATION,ANCESTRY
SCREWDRIVER,HAMMER
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption that each word can be tested for whether it is an M-I Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of M-I Words™, many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: Home isn't an M-I word? Sad

Comment: "BULLET / TRIGGER // DESPAIR / HOPE" - *someone* is a fan of Danganronpa.

Comment: @dcfyj Home is an M/I word, not an M-I word :)

Comment: @Deusovi, _someone_ may be a little excited for Danganronpa V3. It's also the same developer behind the Zero Escape series, hence the words going in there. :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An M-I Word™ is one which has a

> digital root of nine when the word is summed using A=1 to Z=26.

Examples

> DIE = 4 + 9 + 5 = 18 which has a digital root sum of 9 ( or, equivalently, is divisible by 9).
>
>  FOX = 45, LOVE = 54, OASIS = 63, ROUND = 72, MONEY =72, PARADE = 45, SPHINX = 90, BULLET  = 72, DESPAIR = 72, FERRET = 72, WIZARD = 81, DESSERT = 90, MEANING = 63

They we called M-I Word™s because in

> Roman numerals M-I = 1000 - 1 = 999, and the video game [999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Hours,_Nine_Persons,_Nine_Doors) involves a situation about special locks on numbered doors that are based on [digital roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root)   - thanks to Deusovi!

Comment: 99% (+1%) correct!